# Keep div static when other appears

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have a jsfiddle as follows:
http://jsfiddle.net/aritro33/uX7HG/

And I have a problem that when you hit the compose button, the post that appears gets pushed down slightly, but noticeably, by the arrangement of colors that pops up seconds later. How do I keep the post from moving as the arrangement of colors pops up?

Thanks!

HTML:

```
<div id="red" class = "color"></div>
<div id="orange" class = "color"></div>
<div id="yellow" class = "color"></div>
<div id="green" class = "color"></div>
<div id="turquoise" class = "color"></div>
<div id="blue" class = "color"></div>
<div id="purple" class = "color"></div>
<div id="gray" class = "color"></div>
<div id="composeheader">

    <input type="text" id="secondspan" value="Write Header Here:" />
        <div id = "sidebarhex"></div>
    <div id = "taghex"><span id = "withhex" contenteditable = "true">#2AC0A3</span></div>
</div>
<div id="body"><span id="thirdspan" contenteditable="true">Write context text here:</span>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#red {
     background-color: #2ac0a3;
     border-top-left-radius: 5px;
     border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
     position: relative;
     bottom: 220px;
     left: 365px;
 }
 #orange {
     background-color: #25ac92;
     position:relative;
     bottom:236px;
     left: 405px;
 }
 #yellow {
     position: relative;
     bottom: 252px;
     left: 445px;
     background-color:#219982;
 }
 #green {
     position: relative;
     left: 485px;
     bottom: 268px;
     background-color: #1d8672;
 }
 #turquoise {
     position: relative;
     left: 525px;
     bottom: 284px;
     background-color: #197361;
 }
 #blue {
     position: relative;
     left: 565px;
     bottom: 300px;
     background-color: #156051;
 }
 #purple {
     position: relative;
     left: 605px;
     bottom: 316px;
     background-color: #104c41;
 }
 #gray {


     position: relative;
     left: 645px;
     bottom: 332px;
     background-color: #0c3930;
     border-top-right-radius: 5px;
     border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
 }



#composeheader {
     height: 80px;
     width: 500px;
     background-color:#2AC0A3;
     position: relative;
     bottom: 320px;
     left: 365px;
     color: white;
 }
 #secondspan {
     color: white;
     font-family:'Roboto';
     font-size: 40px;
     position: relative;
     background-color: #2AC0A3;
     border: 1px solid #2AC0A3;
     left: 15px;
     top: 10px;
 }
 #body {
     min-height: 100px;
     overflow: hidden;
     width: 500px;
     background-color: #C6EEE6;
     position: relative;
     left: 365px;
     bottom: 320px;
     padding: 20px;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 #thirdspan {
     color: black;
     font-family:'Roboto';
     outline: 0px solid transparent;
 }
#sidebarhex{
    height: 30px;
    width: 7px;
    background-color: #156051;
    position: relative;
    left: 500px;
    bottom: 30px;

}

#taghex{
    height: 30px;
    width: 80px;
    background-color: #219982;
    position: relative;
    left: 420px;
    bottom: 60px;
}

#withhex{
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    position: relative;
    top: 4px;
    left: 9px;
    border: 0px solid transparent;
    outline: none;
}

.color{
    height: 16px;
    width: 40px;
}



#red.active{
    height: 16px;
    width: 45px;
    z-index: 1;
    border: 3px solid white;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 218px;
}




#orange.active{
    height: 16px;
    width: 45px;
    z-index: 1;
    border: 3px solid white;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 233px;
}

#red.orangeselected{
   position: relative;
    bottom: 215px;

}
```

Animation CSS:

```
 .animated {
     -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
     -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
     -ms-animation-duration: 1s;
     -o-animation-duration: 1s;
     animation-duration: 1s;
     -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
     -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
     -ms-animation-fill-mode: both;
     -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
     animation-fill-mode: both;
 }
 .animated.hinge {
     -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
     -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
     -ms-animation-duration: 2s;
     -o-animation-duration: 2s;
     animation-duration: 2s;
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes bounceInDown {
     0% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY(-2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY(30px);
     }
     80% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px)
     }
     100% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @-moz-keyframes bounceInDown {
     0% {
         -moz-transform: translateY(-2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -moz-transform: translateY(30px);
     }
     80% {
         -moz-transform: translateY(-10px)
     }
     100% {
         -moz-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @-ms-keyframes bounceInDown {
     0% {
         -ms-transform: translateY(-2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -ms-transform: translateY(30px);
     }
     80% {
         -ms-transform: translateY(-10px)
     }
     100% {
         -ms-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @-o-keyframes bounceInDown {
     0% {
         -o-transform: translateY(-2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -o-transform: translateY(30px);
     }
     80% {
         -o-transform: translateY(-10px)
     }
     100% {
         -o-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @keyframes bounceInDown {
     0% {
         transform: translateY(-2000px);
     }
     60% {
         transform: translateY(30px);
     }
     80% {
         transform: translateY(-10px)
     }
     100% {
         transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 .bounceInDown {
     -webkit-animation-name: bounceInDown;
     -moz-animation-name: bounceInDown;
     -ms-animation-name: bounceInDown;
     -o-animation-name: bounceInDown;
     animation-name: bounceInDown;
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes bounceInUp {
     0% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY(2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
     }
     80% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY(10px)
     }
     100% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @-moz-keyframes bounceInUp {
     0% {
         -moz-transform: translateY(2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -moz-transform: translateY(-30px);
     }
     80% {
         -moz-transform: translateY(10px)
     }
     100% {
         -moz-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @-ms-keyframes bounceInUp {
     0% {
         -ms-transform: translateY(2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -ms-transform: translateY(-30px);
     }
     80% {
         -ms-transform: translateY(10px)
     }
     100% {
         -ms-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @-o-keyframes bounceInUp {
     0% {
         -o-transform: translateY(2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -o-transform: translateY(-30px);
     }
     80% {
         -o-transform: translateY(10px)
     }
     100% {
         -o-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @keyframes bounceInUp {
     0% {
         transform: translateY(2000px);
     }
     60% {
         transform: translateY(-30px);
     }
     80% {
         transform: translateY(10px)
     }
     100% {
         transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 .bounceInUp {
     -webkit-animation-name: bounceInUp;
     -moz-animation-name: bounceInUp;
     -ms-animation-name: bounceInUp;
     -o-animation-name: bounceInUp;
     animation-name: bounceInUp;
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes bounceInUp {
     0% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY(2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
     }
     80% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY(10px)
     }
     100% {
         -webkit-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @-moz-keyframes bounceInUp {
     0% {
         -moz-transform: translateY(2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -moz-transform: translateY(-30px);
     }
     80% {
         -moz-transform: translateY(10px)
     }
     100% {
         -moz-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @-ms-keyframes bounceInUp {
     0% {
         -ms-transform: translateY(2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -ms-transform: translateY(-30px);
     }
     80% {
         -ms-transform: translateY(10px)
     }
     100% {
         -ms-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @-o-keyframes bounceInUp {
     0% {
         -o-transform: translateY(2000px);
     }
     60% {
         -o-transform: translateY(-30px);
     }
     80% {
         -o-transform: translateY(10px)
     }
     100% {
         -o-transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 @keyframes bounceInUp {
     0% {
         transform: translateY(2000px);
     }
     60% {
         transform: translateY(-30px);
     }
     80% {
         transform: translateY(10px)
     }
     100% {
         transform: translateY()
     }
 }
 .bounceInUp {
     -webkit-animation-name: bounceInUp;
     -moz-animation-name: bounceInUp;
     -ms-animation-name: bounceInUp;
     -o-animation-name: bounceInUp;
     animation-name: bounceInUp;
 }
```

JS:

```
$('#red').click(function(){
    $('#red').addClass('active');
        $('#red').removeClass('orangeselected');
        $('#orange').removeClass('active');
});

$('#orange').click(function(){
    $('#orange').addClass('active');
        $('#red').removeClass('active');
    $('#red').addClass('orangeselected');
});
 $('#sidebarhex').fadeTo(0,1);

        $('#thecolor').addClass('box animated bounceInDown');
        $('.bubble').addClass('box animated bounceInDown');
        $('#composeheader').addClass('box animated bounceInDown');
        $('#body').addClass('box animated bounceInDown');
        setTimeout(function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#red').fadeTo(0, 400);
                $('#orange').fadeTo(0, 400);
                $('#yellow').fadeTo(0, 400);
                $('#green').fadeTo(0, 400);
                $('#turquoise').fadeTo(0, 400);
                $('#blue').fadeTo(0, 400);
                $('#purple').fadeTo(0, 400);
                $('#gray').fadeTo(0, 400);
            }, 400);
            $('#red').addClass('box animated bounceInUp');
            $('#orange').addClass('box animated bounceInUp');
            $('#yellow').addClass('box animated bounceInUp');
            $('#green').addClass('box animated bounceInUp');
            $('#turquoise').addClass('box animated bounceInUp');
            $('#blue').addClass('box animated bounceInUp');
            $('#purple').addClass('box animated bounceInUp');
            $('#gray').addClass('box animated bounceInUp');

        }, 500);

        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#red').addClass('active');
        }, 1050);
```

Comment: Whatever you recently changed is crashing the fiddle. Hi again :-)

Comment: Hi! Are you sure its not just you? @Phlume

Comment: FF and Chrome none of the colors work. The `compose` div that appears also hangs a loooong time before being shown. Previous example was much faster and more responsive to user input. no. Not just me.

Comment: I'm using chrome and it works just fine for me... I've re-updated the jsfiddle, let me know if it works now. @Phlume

Comment: no change. All of the colors in that top bar fail to work. In addition, when I click on "compose" the div that is shown drops down quite a ways... and then nothing happens for about 4-5 seconds.

Comment: Have you tried using another computer? Here is the link again: http://jsfiddle.net/aritro33/y6wBy/ @Phlume

Comment: another computer??? hahah... your funny. Are you going to tell your users to try a new computer if your code doesn't work for them?

Comment: :-) Here, I remade the jsfiddle, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/aritro33/uX7HG/ @Phlume

Comment: Still the same. your previous post/question this fiddle worked fine and all colors worked as expected. Now, after you fiddled with it, the interface does not respond as it used to. Parse your code and see what may have been altered. I'm done here for now...